# several classes implement parent class with varying api

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a class Feature with a pure virtual method.

```
class Feature {
public:
  virtual ~Feature() {}
  virtual const float getValue(const vector<int>& v) const = 0;
};
```

This class is implemented by several classes, for example FeatureA and FeatureB.
A separate class Computer (simplified) uses the getValue method to do some computation.

```
class Computer {
public:
  const float compute(const vector<Feature*>& features, const vector<int>& v) {
    float res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); ++i) {
      res += features[i]->getValue(v);
    }
    return res;
  }
};
```

Now, I am would like to implement FeatureC but I realize that I need additional information in the getValue method. The method in FeatureC looks like

```
const float getValue(const vector<int>& v, const vector<int>& additionalInfo) const;
```

I can of course modify the signature of getValue in Feature, FeatureA, FeatureB to take additionalInfo as a parameter and also add additionalInfo as a parameter in the compute method. But then I may have to modify all those signatures again later if I want to implement FeatureD that needs even more additional info. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to this or if there is a known design pattern that you can point me to for further reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Instead of passing the single vector to `getValue()`, pass a struct.  In this struct you can put the vector today, and more data tomorrow.  Of course, if some concrete runs of your program don't need the extra fields, the need to compute them might be wasteful.  But it will impose no performance penalty if you always need to compute all the data anyway (i.e. if there will always be one FeatureC).
2. Pass to `getValue()` a reference to an object having methods to get the necessary data.  This object could be the Computer itself, or some simpler proxy.  Then the `getValue()` implementations can request exactly what they need, and it can be lazily computed.  The laziness will eliminate wasted computations in some cases, but the overall structure of doing it this way will impose some small constant overhead due to having to call (possibly virtual) functions to get the various data.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  I'd encourage you to up-vote any and all answers you find helpful (and accept whichever one you ultimately find most relevant).  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring the user of your Feature class hierarchy to call different methods based on class defeats polymorphism. Once you start doing `dynamic_cast<>()` you know you should be rethinking your design.

If a subclass requires information that it can only get from its caller, you should change the getValue() method to take an additionalInfo argument, and simply ignore that information in classes where it doesn't matter.

If FeatureC can get additionalInfo by calling another class or function, that's usually a better approach, as it limits the number of classes that need to know about it. Perhaps the data is available from an object which FeatureC is given access to via its constructor, or from a singleton object, or it can be calculated by calling a function. Finding the best approach requires a bit more knowledge about the case.

Comment: "If a subclass requires information that it can only get from its caller, you should change the getValue() method to take an additionalInfo argument, and simply ignore that information in classes where it doesn't matter.": yes, that's what I want to avoid. "Otherwise, if FeatureC can get additionalInfo by calling another class or function, that's a better approach.": could you elaborate ? Do you mean that FeatureC gets additionalInfo in the constructor for example ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is addressed in item 39 of C++ Coding Standards (Sutter, Alexandrescu), which is titled "Consider making virtual functions nonpublic, and public functions nonvirtual."

In particular, one of the motivations for following the Non-Virtual-Interface design pattern (this is what the item is all about) is stated as

> Each interface can take its natural shape: When we separate the public interface
>   from the customization interface, each can easily take the form it naturally
>   wants to take instead of trying to find a compromise that forces them to look
>   identical. Often, the two interfaces want different numbers of functions and/or
>   different parameters; [...]

This is particularly useful

> In base classes with a high cost of change

Another design pattern which is very useful in this case is the Visitor pattern. As for the NVI it applies when base classes (as well as the whole hierarchy) have a high cost of change. You can find plenty of discussion about this design pattern, I suggest you to read the related chapter in Modern C++ (Alexandrescu), which (on the side) gives you a great insight on how to use the (very easy to use) Visitor facilities in [loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/)

I suggest for you to read all of this material and then edit the question so that we can give you a better answer. We can come up with all sort of solutions (e.g. use an additional method which gives the class the additional parameters, if needed) which might well not suit your case.

Try to address the following questions:

1. would a template-based solution fit the problem?
2. would it be feasible to add a new layer of indirection when calling the function?
3. would a "push argument"-"push argument"-...-"push argument"-"call function" method be of help? (this might seem very odd at first, but
   think to something like "cout << arg << arg << arg << endl", where
   "endl" is the "call function")
4. how do you intend to distinguish how to call the function in Computer::compute?

Now that we had some "theory", let's aim for the practice using the Visitor pattern:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FeatureA;
class FeatureB;

class Computer{
    public:
    int visitA(FeatureA& f);

    int visitB(FeatureB& f);
};

class Feature {
public:
  virtual ~Feature() {}
  virtual int accept(Computer&) = 0;
};

class FeatureA{
    public:
    int accept(Computer& c){
        return c.visitA(*this);
    }
    int compute(int a){
        return a+1;
    }
};

class FeatureB{
    public:
    int accept(Computer& c){
        return c.visitB(*this);
    }
    int compute(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
};

int Computer::visitA(FeatureA& f){
        return f.compute(1);
}

int Computer::visitB(FeatureB& f){
        return f.compute(1, 2);
}

int main()
{
    FeatureA a;
    FeatureB b;
    Computer c;
    cout << a.accept(c) << '\t' << b.accept(c) << endl;
}
```

You can try this code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bab2a6fc87a39bbec3efa4eadc725d3e-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).
This is a rough implementation of the Visitor pattern which, as you can see, solves your problem. I strongly advice you not to try to implement it this way, there are obvious dependency problems which can be solved by means of a refinement called the Acyclic Visitor. It is already implemented in Loki, so there is no need to worry about implementing it.

Apart from implementation, as you can see you are not relying on type switches (which, as somebody else pointed out, you should avoid whenever possible) and you are not requiring the classes to have any particular interface (e.g. one argument for the compute function). Moreover, if the visitor class is a hierarchy (make Computer a base class in the example), you won't need to add any new function to the hierarchy when you want to add functionalities of this sort.

If you don't like the visitA, visitB, ... "pattern", worry not: this is just a trivial implementation and you don't need that. Basically, in a real implementation you use template specialization of a visit function.

Hope this helped, I had put a lot of effort into it :)

Comment: you are welcome. I had worked out some more material and a code solution to your problem too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions, to work correctly, needs to have exactly the same "signature" (same parameters and same return type). Otherwise, you just get a "new member function", which isn't what you want.

The real question here is "how does the calling code know it needs the extra information".

You can solve this in a few different ways - the first one is to always pass in `const vector <int>& additionalInfo`, whether it's needed or not.

If that's not possible, because there isn't any `additionalInfo` except for in the case of `FeatureC`, you could have an "optional" parameter - which means use a pointer to vector (`vector<int>* additionalInfo`), which is NULL when the value is not available.

Of course if `additionalInfo` is a value that is something that can be stored in the FeatureC class, then that would also work.

Another option is to extend the base class `Feature` to have two more options:

```
class Feature {
public:
  virtual ~Feature() {}
  virtual const float getValue(const vector<int>& v) const = 0;
  virtual const float getValue(const vector<int>& v, const vector<int>& additionalInfo) { return -1.0; };   
  virtual bool useAdditionalInfo() { return false; }
};
```

and then make your loop something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); ++i) {
  if (features[i]->useAdditionalInfo())
  {
       res += features[i]->getValue(v, additionalInfo);
  }
  else
  {
     res += features[i]->getValue(v);
  }
}
```